# Python cx_Oracle loading CSV using executemany() gives "Required argument 'parameters' (pos 2) not found"

Tags: python, database, oracle, pandas, cx-oracle

My intention is to load the csv file in a Oracle table using Python.

1. I'm truncating table, if data already exists - This is working
2. I'm checking the count for testing purpose - This is working
3. I'm trying to Insert data from file in to Oracle. I'm getting issue:

   > 'Required argument 'parameters' (pos 2) not found'

Code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd 

column_names = 
['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6','Col7','Col8','Col9']
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\file.dat", names=column_names, sep='|')

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('*', '*', sid='*') 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='*', password='*', dsn=*) 
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('Truncate table Table_Name')
c.execute('select count(1) from Table_Name')
for row in c:
print(row)        
for lines in df:
c = conn.cursor()
print("I want to print lines")
res = c.executemany("""Insert into Code_Extract (OPERATION,
                 LIST_COUNTRY_ID,LIST_CODE,SOURCE_SYSTEM_CODE,CODE_USUAL,
                   INT_LIST_CODE,INT_MDM_CODE,CODE_STATUS,MDM_CODE) 
                   Values(df['col1'],df['Col2'],df['Col3'],df['Col4'],df['Col5'],df['Col6'],df['Col7'],df['Col8'],df['Col9'])""")
conn.commit()
c.execute('select count(1) from Table_Name')
for row in c:
    print(row)
c.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

My expectation is whenever I receive files it should be automatically loaded in to Oracle from the specified path.

Comment: Indentation is off. I don't know how that for loop and execuremany are supposed to interact there (maybe a pandas thing I'm not familiar with but why both?). I'd be happier if you could post the actual query and db-error for one line of the csv file, which you should also provide.

Comment: If your data is in a CSV file on disk, the fastest way to load it in Oracle database is likely to be SQL*Loader, which is free in Oracle Instant Client https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-instant-client-122-now-has-sqlloader-and-data-pump

Answer (score 0):

The parameters to executemany() are indeed required. See the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.executemany) for more information.

You've put the parameters inside the SQL, but instead they should be specified as bind variables, as in `values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9)`. You would then pass the data as a list of sequences to executemany(). Hopefully that's clear! You can see an example [here](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BindInsert.py).

Comment: Anthony Tuininga has a useful blog post [Efficient and Scalable Batch Statement Execution in Python cx_Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle) with lots of examples of executemany()